# Linq to Mongodb dynamic update function

Tags: c#, linq, mongodb

I am trying to update a collection dynamically by using generics. I have a working solution which is:

```
 MongoCollection symbolcollection= database.GetCollection<Symbol>("Symbols")  
var query3 = Query<Symbol>.EQ(e => e.Id, ("0000000000021325640.0");  
var update = Update<Symbol>.Set(e => e.Name, "abc"); // update modifiers  
symbolcollection.Update(query3, update);
```

But my question is how can I update an item in a collection dynamically without explicitly declaring the collection type?

I tried something like this:

```
var query = Query.EQ("_id", new BsonObjectId(ObjectId.Parse(id)));
        var update = Update<TEntity>.Set(e => e, entity);
        var collection = GetCollection();
        collection.Update(query, update);
```

but it throws an exception:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in MongoDB.Driver.dll but was not handled in user code 
>  
> **Exception Message:** Value cannot be null.
>   Parameter name: name

Is there a solution to this or is the working solution the only way to achieve this?

Comment: You can not update like that, if you want to create global method to handle  all update, then you should pass list of Expression to update method

Comment: thanks man. I just thought of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally got it working by building the query before passing it into the final method to do the update:

```
 var symbolToUpdate = Update<Symbol>.Set(e => e.Name, symbol.Name);
            UpdateItem(symbolToUpdate, id);

    public void UpdateItem(UpdateBuilder<TEntity> symbolToUpdate, string id)
            {
                var query = Query.EQ("_id", new BsonObjectId(ObjectId.Parse(id)));
                var collection = GetCollection();
                collection.Update(query, symbolToUpdate);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass Action to method

```
public void Update(ObjectId id, Expression<Func<Entity , object>> updateExpr , object value)
{
    var query = Query.EQ("_id", new BsonObjectId(id));
    var update = Update<TEntity>.Set(updateExpr, value);
    var collection = GetCollection();
    collection.Update(query, update);
}
```

And call like:

```
Update(ObjectId.GenerateNewId(), x => x.Name, "NAME_VALUE");
```